# Format date in ES6

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6

I am formatting a Date, with not momentjs or any other library, just pure JS. And I want to know if there is a way to simplify this with ES6

```
let currentDate = new Date(); 

const videosInformation = {
  time: currentDate.getHours() + ':' + currentDate.getMinutes(),
  date: (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear(),
  gameId: Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1)
};
```

I saw that in the DOM you use something like `` renderSomething={`something: ${someObj}`} ``

so you don't have to do `renderSomething={"something: " + {someObj}}`

is there something I should use to do that kind of format?

Comment: If you are just talking about template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's nothing in ES2015 that added something like `strftime` no. There's an ECMAScript internationalisation spec [ecma-402](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-8) which enables localised time:

```
let [date, time] = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US').split(', ');

const videosInformation = {
  time,
  date,
  gameId: Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1)
};
```

Which would give you US localized **8/4/2015** and **5:29:19 PM** Or if you really want a 24 hour clock:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: false})
```

Then you can do a substring on the time if you want to strip out the seconds.

You can read more about date and time at [MDT docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: should be `let [date, time]`