# How to format date in React-Native-IOS

Tags: date, react-native, date-format

I have used following to display date:

```
var formattedDate = new Date(date).toString();
    console.log("DATE >> ", formattedDate);
```

Result:

> 'Date >>' , 'Wed Nov 23 2015 05:30:00'

My `date` format is as follows:

```
date= 2015-11-23
```

but I want to format my `date` in **`"DD MMM YYYY"`** format in `react-native-ios.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792398/format-date-in-es6)

Answer (score 8):

Use date.getDay(), date.getMonth() and date.getYear() to extract day months year from date, then use it as you like :)

```
var formattedDate = new Date(date);
var newDate = formattedDate.getDay().toString() + " " + formattedDate.getMonth().toString() + " " + formattedDate.getYear().toString();
```

as Alternative you can use moment.js as well. have lots of useful functions.

```js
var newDate = moment(Date(yourDate)).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Import Moment JS :

```js
import moment from 'moment';
```

Install Moment JS :

```
npm install moment
```

Comment: Using this: `var newDate = moment(Date(yourDate)).format('DD-MM-YYYY');`.             I am getting error `Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: moment`

Comment: @userashu19 first install and import moment module.

Comment: `formattedDate.getYear().toString()` is giving me 120, instead of 2020. Not sure why

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateee = new Date(this.dateUpdate);//this.dateUpdate = 1488506939000
var wholeDate = dateee.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (dateee.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateee.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + ('0' + dateee.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + dateee.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
console.log('----- ' + this.dateUpdate + '     ' + wholeDate);


//----- 1488506939000  2017-03-03 10:08
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)'s `format()` function

`npm install date-fns --save`

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), 'MMMM Do, YYYY H:mma')
```

[Documentation for `format()`](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format)

Moment is great, but very large for common usages, and unfortunately not modular so you have to import the whole package to use it.

Answer (score 0):

@Ataomega. To get the day of a Date instance, you need to use formattedDate.getDate().toString() instead of formattedDate.getDay().toString(). Otherwise, you're getting the day of the week. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
handleDatePicked = (date) => {
    console.log(date);
    var ds = date.toString();

    var date = moment(new Date(ds.substr(0, 16)));
    console.log("54874=========>"+date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

    this.setState({ 'date_of_birth': date.format("DD/MM/YYYY") });

};
```

**Output:**

```
Sun Mar 17 2019 15:38:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
17/03/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the librairy moment : https://momentjs.com/
And you can format any date using :

```
moment().format('yourDateHere, DD:MM:YYYY');
```

Comment: what is yourDateHere? How can we place our variable here?